# three.js What is the best approach to create a thousands elements that can be clickable?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, three.js

I need to draw a thousands square with image texture that must have stable size despite of zooming and it must be clickable.
Image texture the same for all square.

Using ParticleSystem doesn't allows me make it clickable.

If I use CubeGeometry, I have to scale on every zoom event and it's very very slowly.
What is the best approach to create a  thousands elements where everyone can be clickable?

I use THREE.WebGLRenderer 61.

Event click handler:

```
function onDocumentMouseClick(event) {
        layerMap.update();
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        var ray = projector.pickingRay(vector, camera);
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Thousands** of textured THREE.CubeGeometrys...sounds like way too many to be responsive. A Wacky Idea:  How about limiting your 3d canvas to be a "viewport" into the universe of thousands of objects (rendering only 50-100 cubes in the viewport).  To handle the zoom process, you could overlay a canvas (2d context) to render the zoom.  The 2d wouldn't be responsive during the zoom process--but you probably wouldn't need it to be. Then when the zoom is complete, hide the 2d canvas and resume with 3d in the new viewport position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution, I use ParticleSystem for displaying many objects with texture.
On click event I check all vertex to find the most close one to clicked point, if distance is close enough I call a needed method. It works very fast.